# What does the line of code `np.transpose(image_tensor, (2, 1, 0))` do?

Tags: python, numpy

I was looking at some code and there was a line that said:

```
# transpose to standard format
# You might want to comment this line or reverse the shuffle
# if you will use a learning algorithm like CNN, since they like their channels separated.
image_standard_form = np.transpose(image, (2, 1, 0))
```

and I couldn't figure out what it did. I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) but I didn't quite understand what "axes" meant in the transpose parameter. It said:

```
axes : list of ints, optional
By default, reverse the dimensions, otherwise permute the axes according to the values given.
```

but it didn't really say what it was for. Also, the example using transpose and a tuple wasn't very insightful (or at least didn't show me what it was suppose to do). Can someone explain to me what its suppose to do?

I also did an example of my own to figure out what it does but I wasn't 100% I understood it:

```
>>> x
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.]]])
>>> np.transpose(x, (2, 1, 0))
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.]]])
```

Comment: Start with an array like `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)`.  It is easier to identify the action of functions like this when the shapes and values are all different.  This transpose is a generalization of the common 2d transpose.  Make sure you understand that, and try to imagine the possibilities when the array is 3d or larger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume you want to access an element with:

```
elem = image[i, j, k]
```

After the transpose, now you should access the same element with:

```
elem = image_standard_form[k, j, i]
```

The `(2,1,0)` in transpose means the permutation to the indices.

For the CNN, it probably want turn a tensor of shape:

```
[width, height, channels]
```

into:

```
[channels, height, width]
```

Comment: I was looking at the docs for convolution/cross-correlation in TensorFlow (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#convolution) and it seems that they use `Given an input tensor of shape [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]` for a CNN. So channels at the end it seems.

Comment: @Pinocchio It depends. You can set image format to `NCHW` or `NHWC`(default) in TF by supplying `data_format` argument to `tf.nn.conv2d`.

Comment: the thing I find very mysterious is that if you give `(0,2,3,1)` then the images are shown sides ways. Do you know whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

For suppose lets take an example to show image using pyplot from matplotlib library.

Generally,

The image in the form of numpy.array has width x height x no_of channels(rgb or rgba). Only this type helps us to plot it. Suppose if you want to rotate image clockwise then the numpy.array need to use transpose by interchanging the values of width and height.

At this point we can use transpose,
**Usage:**
example array(**img**) with shape 32x28x3 (width(index 0),height (index 1),channels(index 2))
To rotate it, just interchange width and height by doing
** np.transpose(img,(1,0,2)) -> here index positions need to interchange

Comment: This answer needs more clarity